# Spring BOOT autoscaling with actuator metrics

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator, hpa

I want to automatically scale my Backend Spring Boot application using actuator metrics such as: jvm.threads.live, jvm.memory.used, process.cpu.usage. My application is deployed in a kubernetes cluster, for this I use the HPA controller in my cluster. How do I get these metrics and configure my HPA yaml file to monitor and observe these parameters and add a threshold for each metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [prometheus adapter](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter) for k8s API to be able to use actuator's metrics in HPA. Here's an example of [usage](https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/scale-your-spring-boot-application-in-kubernetes/).

You need such an intermediate agent as Prometheus, as it does many necessary things for you, such as collecting these metrics from all pods within the autoscaling group, storing metrics, and providing query language to define an autoscaling policy.

Comment: what about kube-metrics-adapter by zalando ! there is a good sample to follow it ?

Comment: @mimo2000 didn't try, but looks like a more generic tool not only for Prometheus, looks promising

Comment: thanks a lot @Kirill Liubun  :)